# Automate the Import Function from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets

Is there any way to automate the Import Function from Google Sheets in Javascript?

Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

               var dataDestinationUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s3Pu-Sr4BwaBTqKYX2BDLZICf8sNko5D6v6O-ysot7g';
               var dataSource = 'c:\MyExcel.xlsx'


               function importData() { 
                   dataDestinationUrl.import (DataSource)
               }

         </script>

     </head>
     <body>

          <input type="button" onclick="importData" value="Submit" />
     </body>
</html>
```

What I'm looking to do is something like this:

https://www.dataeverywhere.com/use-excel-sheets

but because corporation restrictions I cannot have adds-on. 
However, I can program an script in Javascript to do it and use the script.

Further explanation:

- Most reports are done in Excel because are connected to a database in IBM Cognos TM1 through a plug-in or add-in, The data sits in IBM Cognos TM1 and through the plug-in is push to Excel.
- However, Google Sheets doesn't have (as far as I know) any way to connect to IBM Cognos TM1.
- Reports are extensive, several tabs, many rows and columns so copying and pasting all that information from many reports to Google Sheets won't be a solution.
- There is also the import solution, but this is not only for 1 file 1 time. There are multiple files that are update daily, weekly, biweekly and monthly, so the import option is not a solution either. Anything that would need human intervention won't be really a solution. I need to find out how to automatically synchronize Google Sheets with Excel Files.
- I was trying to think on a way to "Import", Transfer, Synchronize or anything similar so I could indicate where is the location of my Excel file (C;\MyExcel.xlsx) and automatically have the information replicated into a Google Sheets.

Can I maybe to this with the Google Sheets API? If so, do you know how?

Thank you very much

Comment: Is it okay if a new file in Google Drive is created every time or do you need the data to be appended to an existing Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

I'd script the following steps:

1. CSV-Download from Google Sheets
2. Put the CSV into a shared directory
3. Write a simple import script for TM1 TurboIntegrator
4. Trigger this import TI by using a TM1 chore or TM1 REST API Call

Link to TM1 API:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home/wiki/W181f1083f3dd_455f_b2f8_f63c4a9c8010/page/TM1%20REST%20API%2010.2.2?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Look at **TeamOne** Google Sheets add-on: https://succeedium.com/teamone
https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/teamone/112725458607

It allows to import\export data from/to TM1, manage TM1 users, cubes, views, dimensions, subsets, processes. Compare and deploy code, search TM1 model. Many other cool features, like TEAMONE formula to pull data from TM1 server